# directing the output to .txt file and automatically naming the file

Tags: output, raspberry-pi

I'm new to python and writing code in general. I want to direct the output of a users input into a .txt file (if possible). And if possible name it after the input in line 3. Thank you for any help or advice

```
userName = raw_input("login = ")
print "Welcome,", userName
number = raw_input("ID number = ")
weight = raw_input("Weight = ")
```

Answer (score 1):

Write inside a file is quite easy in Python:

```
f = open(number + '.txt', 'w') #create a file using the given input
f.write(userName + " " + weight)
f.close()
```

For further references : http://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/inputoutput.html